# Soundmax drivers fail to install

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, audio, drivers, motherboard

Okay, so here is the problem

I have a older Motherboard (ASUS Rampage Formula 1 ... The Original) and I recently decided to install windows 8.1 on to the computer. Without doing any research I later discovered that this MOBO has NO drivers for Windows 8/8.1 ... I am trying to get my Supremefx II sound card (That came with the MOBO) to work. However there is no entry for the sound card in the Device Manager so it is not even being detected, and any drivers that I find (And try to run in compatibility mode) just say

**The audio driver files do not support your hardware.**

Picture Related:
[image: Related Picture]

**Is there any way to get this driver to work?**

Can i do .INI configuration changes, try Different Drivers. I really like windows 8 and I have no problem with windows 7 (I prefer 7 actually) but there is just no time to copy all of my files and install windows 7 ... I will if it is a last resort but I want to try everything I can before hand.

**To clarify any confusion**

I have already gone to the ASUS Website to get the drivers. If you go to [this link (MOBO Support Page)](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_FORMULA/HelpDesk_Download/) and click the drop down menu there isn't any selection for windows 8/8.1. And as I said the windows 7 versions (I have 64 bit so just in case I tried both) give me that error message.

**And as KEK suggested**

> Alternatively; locating driver files manually
>
> Do you have a backup of of your old Win 7 install before upgrading to 8.1? Drivers should be located in %windir%\system32\DriverStore\

I do have the old hard drive from the original windows 7 copy but I cant select the device (Supremefx II) in device manager because it doesn't even show up. The only audio devices are my Logitech G930s and My Graphics card (NVIDIA) HDMI port audio

Picture related:

[image: Related Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the drivers from ASUS?
[www.asus.com/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_FORMULA/HelpDesk_Download/](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_FORMULA/HelpDesk_Download/)

The Audio driver says SoundMAX, but a thread at TomsHardware said it also resolved problems for Supremefix II.

### Locating driver files manually

Do you have a backup of of your old Win 7 install before upgrading to 8.1?
Drivers should be located in `%windir%\system32\DriverStore\`

Open `Device Manager`, click on the device with missing driver (labeled with a yellow **!**), chose to install from a local source and point it to the `DriverStore` folder (and include subfolders). Device manager will find the drivers automatically.

### Device Manager says there's no missing drivers; Locating the correct Supremefix device and reinstall correct driver

According to your last Device manager picture, your computer doesn't even detect the Supremefix II device, OR somehow the "NVIDIA High Definition Audio"-driver seems to be sufficient for the Supremefix.

Since Device Manager says there's no problem, does the sound card work? Do you get any sound at all?

If not, continue on

We'll have to check all those **NVIDIA High Definition Audio** devices to see which one is actually the Supremefix II device.
Double click on each of them and click on the **Details** tab. In the dropbox menu, choose **Hardware Ids**. We're looking for the device ID, see picture below.

[image: Reference pic Device Manager]

In my picture it says DEV_0040, so the Device ID is 0040. Go to [pcidatabase.com](http://pcidatabase.com) and type in the device ID in the upper right search bar. PCIDatabase will then tell you (most likely) which device this is.
Do this for all the Nvidia devices, I suspect one of them must be the Supremefix II soundcard.

After you've found the correct one, you must right click that device and choose to **Uninstall** it. This will remove the drivers. Then click on the Refresh button in your Device manager (blue icon in the top, labeled *Search for hardware changes*).
You should now see a device with a missing driver. Double click on this device, choose to install drivers from a local directory and point it to your Windows 7 backup (DriverStore folder as mentioned earlier).

Comment: I should have made it more clear in my post but I have already tried the first one. If you go to that link and click the drop down menu there isn't any selection for windows 8/8.1. And as I said the win7 versions give me that error message. However I do have the old hard drive from the original windows 7 copy but I cant select the device (Supremefx II) in device manager because it doesn't even show up. The only audio devices are my Logitech G930s and My Graphics card (NVIDIA) HDMI port audio

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Yeah I meant the Windows 7 drivers from ASUS, not 8, but if those didn't work then it's ok. Please see my updated post, I hope it could be of assistance... it's just a shot in the dark really. It's weird that you have no devices with missing drivers. Sound like your Supremefix is installed, but maybe with wrong drivers, even though that's very rare (wrong drivers will usually be declined automatically)

Comment: Well, do you think that maybe the sound card would not show up if the MOBO's chipset drivers are not compatible or out of date. I can't remember where I read it but when I was doing as much research as I could someone suggested to another user (For a different but 'similar' problem) that it might not be detected due to MOBOs chipset not picking it up. AND if thats the case I know that windows 7 automatically installs chipset drivers (And the asus support page doesnt have windows 7 chipset drivers). However, I dont know if thats the case for windows 8. Is it a possibility?

Comment: Also I confirmed that all of the Hardware ID's Under NVIDIA show up as the graphics card

Comment: Actually I believe that the Sound Card is dead ... I just bit the bullet and installed Windows 7 then tried the install but it still never showed up. I will set your answer as the correct one though for maybe someone else who will need a solution! Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Oww alright, I'm not sure how to test the soundcard itself when it's integrated on the motherboard. Sorry I couldn't help you, but thanks a lot for the answer points!

Comment: Don't worry it's no big deal. And it wasn't integrated (That is how I found out) I thought maybe the PCIe slot was dead but then switched them (the sound card and the wifi card) and the sound card still never showed :S

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question for future users who stumble upon this.

**This may apply to anyone who has:**

- An Asus Rampage Formula MOBO (The Original) - Because this is the MOBO I have that had this problem.

or

- A motherboard that does not have an integrated soundcard ***BUT*** it comes with one to put in a expansion slot.

  1. Inspect your motherboard and take note of all expansion slots on the
     MOBO.
  2. Take into account any slots that are colored different (For example
     I have a PCIe slot closer to my CPU that is a matte black while all
     others are a teal)
  3. Install the sound card (that did not work on the other PCIe slots)
     into the "different" slot.
  4. Startup and install the drivers as normal. Drivers should install
     normally!

I believe the "different" colored expansion slot is a dedicated slot for the soundcard!